# Beeline/Hive2 variables passed from script getting truncated

Tags: shell, hive, beeline

I have a script from which i pass the parameters to hive variable. The entire flow is as below.One of the hive variable is getting truncated.

## cat << script.sh

```
beeline -u "$HIVESERVER" \
-f $path_to.hql \
--hivevar TRGT_DB=$HIVE_TRGT_DB \
--hivevar SRC_CLMN=$SOURCE_CLMNS \
--hivevar INBND_DB=$HIVE_SRC_DB \
--hivevar SRC_TBL=$SOURCE_TABLE \
--hivevar TRGT_TBL=$TRGT_TABLE \
```

## All the variables are passed correctly except the column variable (SRC_CLMN) which is getting truncated

SRC_CLMN is grepped from a file as below.

```
SRC_CLMN=`cat source_column.tbl | grep table | (some sed functions)`
```

#### Output of SRC_CLMN variable:

trim(regexp_replace(col1, '[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')) as col1,trim(col2) as col2,trim(regexp_extract(col1,"\(([^)]+)\)", 1)) as col3,trim(col4) as col4,trim(col5) as col5,trim(col6) as col6,'' as col7,trim(col8) as col8,trim(col9) as col9,trim(col10) as col10,trim(col11) as col11,trim(col12) as col12,trim(col13) as col13

When i print the variable it's printing the whole string.

**But when i print the hive variable using SET SRC_CLMN; i see only  till "trim(regexp_replace(col1,"**

So this is throwing an error in hive query.

Answer (score 0):

**Output of SRC_CLMN variable:**

trim(regexp_replace(col1, '[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')) as col1,trim(col2) as col2,trim(regexp_extract(col1,"(([^)]+))", 1)) as col3,trim(col4) as col4,trim(col5) as col5,trim(col6) as col6,'' as col7,trim(col8) as col8,trim(col9) as col9,trim(col10) as col10,trim(col11) as col11,trim(col12) as col12,trim(col13) as col13

as you can see in the output there is single quotations  '[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')) you have to use skip character to make them available in your string

simply that's how the variable save it 
SRC_CLMN=***'trim(regexp_replace(col1, '***[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')) as col1,trim(col2) as col2,trim(regexp_extract(col1,"(([^)]+))", 1)) as col3,trim(col4) as col4,trim(col5) as col5,trim(col6) as col6,'' as col7,trim(col8) as col8,trim(col9) as col9,trim(col10) as col10,trim(col11) as col11,trim(col12) as col12,trim(col13) as col13

if you check the Bold Italic part i marked, you will see it starts with a quotations and ends with one, so for the variable thats the string

you need to handle all the quotations with skip characters, you can use **sed** to do so to replace all ' and add skip character \'